# Set UINavigationController as root view controller for UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, rootview

It might sound a little bit unusual, and before anyone asks why would anyone be doing this - it seems that this can't be done programatically, while in storyboard you can set reference from one `UINavigationController` to other to be his root...

Comment: Why can you not do this programmatically? The documentation says the only restriction is that it can not be a UITabBarController and there is a separate init method for that. I won't ask why 8^).

Comment: I get runtime error :-)